# Heapify needs to be ran multiple times

Tags: c++

For some odd reason, I need to run my heapify function multiple times for it to return the right heap array. I am not too good with recursive functions and I have tried to write it by hand and trace my function but I get lost sometimes.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void heapSort(int array[], size_t size);
void heapify(int array[], size_t gIndex, size_t size);
size_t left(size_t index);
size_t right(size_t index);
size_t parent(size_t index);

int main(){
    static const size_t SIZE = 9;
    int arr[] = { 13, 14, 15, 18, 11, 12, 17, 16, 90};
    heapify(arr, 0, SIZE);
    //heapify(arr, 0, SIZE);
    //heapify(arr, 0, SIZE);

    cout << "---\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

size_t left(size_t index){
    return (2 * index) + 1;
}
size_t right(size_t index){
    return (2 * index) + 2;
}
size_t parent(size_t index){
    return (index - 1) / 2;
}
void heapify(int array[], size_t gIndex, size_t size){
    size_t index = gIndex;
    int head = array[index];
    int xright = array[right(index)];
    int xleft = array[left(index)];

    if ((left(index) >= size )){
        return;
    }
    else if (head < xleft){
        array[index] = xleft;
        array[left(index)] = head;
        heapify(array, index, size);
    }
    else if (head < xright){
        array[right(index)] = head;
        array[index] = xright;
        heapify(array, index, size);

    }
    else if (head > xright && head > xleft){
        size_t newind = gIndex + 1;
        heapify(array, newind, size);
    }


}


void heapSort(int array[], size_t size){

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading `heapify` line by line:

```
int xright = array[right(index)];
int xleft = array[left(index)];
```

Here you go out of array bounds because index can be bigger than `size / 2`. So you have undefined behavior already, but in practice this either crashes or initializes `xright` and `xleft` to some garbage values.

```
if ((left(index) >= size )){
    return;
}
```

If `left(index) == size - 1` the execution goes on, but in this case `right(index) == size`. So you have garbage in `xright`, and later you assign it to `array[index]` thus bringing in some garbage value. Also here: `array[right(index)] = head` you write outside array bounds, thus exhibiting undefined behavior again (as if once is not enough).

**Update**
And actually overall you are doing it wrong. First, you should invoke `heapify` for both `left(index)` and `right(index)` (if there is one). Thus you'll have maximums of left and right subtrees at left and right positions. Then find maximum of `array[index]`, `array[left(index)]` and `array[right(index)]` and exchange it with `array[index]`.

Comment: I have deleted the code for xright and xleft, that was something I added later. This is originally what I had which checked if the left or right access went out of bound.
http://pastebin.com/4dLxSJ2N

Comment: Yeah, sorry, the code markup doesn't seem to work here. I put a pastebin link.

Comment: Interesting. To go from the bottom to top in terms of subtrees, I should use the parent function on the last element in the array? Then should I do my heapify from there and work myself upwards?

Comment: @mdislam I gave you a direction. I can't do your homework for you, sorry.

Comment: I have tried again, can you tell me why it is not working?
http://pastebin.com/G0R9tY2V

I get: 14
18
15
16
11
12
17
13

Comment: @mdislam again, you should heapify both left and right subtrees regardless of what is there, and only after that compare their roots to the root of the tree.

Comment: I followed a psuedo code, and got this: http://pastebin.com/vf4unGsE It doesn't seem to do anything..